# I'm attempting to call a function from the context in the componentDidMount function but i'm getting a Cannot read property of undefined error

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am attempting to call an initial data function to setup the state in Context.  This should set the state of the Context with the MetaDataData.json object from a component with some initial values for testing.  It is currently giving me an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialDataLoad' of undefined`

I'm not really sure what is causing this and any help would be appreciated.

```
MetaDateContainer.js
```

```
import React from 'react'
//This is a json file with some dummy data in it for testing
import MetaDataData from '../../metaData'

class MetaDataContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.context.initialDataLoad(MetaDataData)
  }
}

render() {
return(
  <div/>
  )
}

MetaDataContainer.contextType = ProductInfoContext

export default MetaDataContainer
```

```
ProductInfoContext.JS
```

```
import React from "react";

const ProductInfoContext = React.createContext();

export default ProductInfoContext;
```

```
ProductInfoProvider.js
```

```
import React from "react";
import ProductInfoContext from './ProductInfoContext';

class ProductInfoProvider extends React.Component {

  state = {
    metaData: {}

  };

  initialDataLoad = (initialData) => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState({metaData: initialData})
  }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductInfoContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductInfoContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductInfoProvider;
```

Comment: Additionally the console.log in the initalDataLoad function never gets called and i've confirmed with a console.log in the componentDidMount that metaDataData exists with three objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually Provider that sets the value and consumer uses the value. You are trying to set value in consuming `MetaDataContainer.js` by calling `initialDataLoad` function on context but this method is not present on context hence the error.

Ideally you should set initial value in `ProductInfoProvider` may be consuming MetaData.json file.

Working [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2vqnwqx5w)

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: So the issue is that this will update every time that the component refreshed and essentially will make it so that it is non-persistent because it resets back to the original const.

Comment: You could give update function from provider that could be used by consumer to update state. Update [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2vqnwqx5w)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to access context from `props` instead directly like `this.context.initialDataLoad(MetaDataData)`

```
class MetaDataContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.initialDataLoad(MetaDataData)
  }
}

render() {
return(
  <div/>
  )
}
```

Comment: So when i do this i get a notice that a depreciated symbol is used that is the only reason why i changed it to the old way of implementing this.  Additionally I tried using the hooks but since it's in a class it wasn't allowed.

Also this doesn't fix the issue.